# New office wireless setup, printer only accessible from one AP

Tags: wifi, mac, printer

We had Comcast install their "WiFi Pro" package yesterday which essentially was just adding two APs to our current set up. The APs are connected by ethernet to wall jacks which are connected directly to the Comcast modem/router.

Both APs broadcast the same SSID, and presumably the WiFi Pro is set up for devices to connect to either AP, switching when necessary unbeknownst to the end users.

We also have a printer (Canon LBP251) configured with AirPrint. It is connected to the network being broadcast by the new APs, and everyone nearby the printer can print without issue. However, some of the employees located on the other side of the office cannot detect the printer.

I am guessing that users connected to the same AP as the printer can print, and users who are connected to the other AP cannot. Wondering what I can do to allow users connected to either AP to "find" the printer.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as someone who doesn't consider herself a Mac guru...

Airprint is, as near as I can tell, reliant upon Bonjour.  You would have to somehow convince the AP to route Bonjour packets between the two access points, or use a different protocol.

I don't have any personal experience with your Comcast access points, either, but based on [this Superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/730288/why-do-some-wifi-routers-block-multicast-packets-going-from-wired-to-wireless) this is a common situation with Bonjour.  Basically, Bonjour is a link-local multicast protocol and you need to do workarounds in order to route the packets across devices, which your APs may or may not suport.